# spread operator to copy values to nested object dynamically using array forEach loop

Tags: javascript, object

This is the code I made, its actually from the react project I am working on, where I wanted to add more key-value pairs under particular keys. So I made a similar sample code to know how to do it, but unfortunately, I can't find a solution on the internet. 
Please help

```
const filteredSearchItems=[{
  "id":"das",
  "value":45
},
{
  "id":"das3",
  "value":48
},
{
  "id":"das4",
  "value":47
},
{
  "id":"das5",
  "value":46
},

]
let savedFilter = "";
const savefilter = () => {
    const saveName = "fooCriteria";
    filteredSearchItems.forEach(item => {  
        if (!savedFilter) {
          savedFilter={ [saveName]: { [item.id]: item.value } };
        } else
          savedFilter={...savedFilter.saveName,...{
            ...savedFilter.saveName,
            ...{ [item.id]: item.value }
          }};
    });
  };
savefilter();

console.log("savedFilter :",savedFilter)
```

**output**

```
savedFilter : { das5: 46 }
```

My **Expected output** that I wanted

```
{ fooCriteria: { das: 45, das3: 48, das4: 47, das5: 46 } }
```

PS: I wanted to give fooCriteria as savename variable there is a reason. since the name of the object is determined by the user

`const saveName = document.getElementById("seachSaveInput").value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `forEach` `reduce` makes more sense.

```js
const filteredSearchItems = [
  {
    'id': 'das',
    'value': 45
  },
  {
    'id': 'das3',
    'value': 48
  },
  {
    'id': 'das4',
    'value': 47
  },
  {
    'id': 'das5',
    'value': 46
  }

];
const savedFilter = {};
const saveFilter = () => {
  const saveName = 'fooCriteria';

  savedFilter[saveName] = filteredSearchItems.reduce((saved, item) => {
    saved[item.id] = item.value;
    return saved;
  }, savedFilter[saveName] || {});
};
saveFilter();

console.log('savedFilter :', savedFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const filteredSearchItems=[{"id":"das","value":45},{"id":"das3","value":48},{"id":"das4","value":47},{"id":"das5","value":46}];

let fooCriteria = filteredSearchItems.reduce((acc,{id,value})=>(acc[id]=value,acc),{});

console.log({fooCriteria})
```

You can use `reduce` method

Comment: You *can*, but there's no reason to. I'm with [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544), almost every use of `reduce` is a mistake.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why exactly, this Twitter post don't explain anything

Comment: @DanStarns - I thought the discussion under it explained things quite well. I (and Brian and others) find `reduce` over-complicated relative to a simple loop in the majority of cases. It's maybe okay for the things it's actually for (aggregating results, like sums), but when you use it just as a general-purpose iterator as above (particularly when combined with the comma operator), it's just...complicated. `acc` above never changes, which is the bar something has to clear for me to even think about using `reduce`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you not think that the word 'reduce' fits both the requirements of this answer and function well. taking a larger or multiple items and crunching them into a smaller one. "reduction refers to the rewriting of an expression into a simpler form"

Comment: @DanStarns The *word*? ...maybe? I would never say "I want to reduce this array of objects into an object with properties" but if I tilt my head sideways... :-) However, my view (and I'm not alone -- but then, neither are you!) is that the `Array.prototype.reduce` function, specifically, is unnecessarily complicated where a simple loop suffices, as it does here. When the accumulator doesn't change, as above, my view is that `reduce` is the wrong tool. (And often even when the accumulator *does* change.) I get that you have a different view, which is fine. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I appreciate your point of view & great to discuss it :). I do believe that the variable choice of `acc` is very misleading & the function can seem very complicated compared to a for-loop. On the other hand, the function name 'reduce' is inherited from the mathematical term & in this example, there is definitely some reduction going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a shallow copy with spread notation:

```
// If you want to add to the [saveName] entry if it exists:
savedFilter = {...savedFilter, [saveName]: savedFilter ? {...savedFilter[saveName]} : {}};
// If you want to *replace* the [saveName] entry, not add to it:
savedFilter = {...savedFilter, [saveName]: {}};
```

then update the result with a loop:

```
for (const {id, value} of filteredSearchItems) {
    savedFilter[saveName][id] = value;
}
```

Here's an example assuming you want to replace the `[saveName]` property if it exists:

```js
const filteredSearchItems=[{
  "id":"das",
  "value":45
},
{
  "id":"das3",
  "value":48
},
{
  "id":"das4",
  "value":47
},
{
  "id":"das5",
  "value":46
},

];

let savedFilter = {somethingAlreadyThere: 42};
const saveName = "fooCriteria";
savedFilter = {...savedFilter, [saveName]: {}};
for (const {id, value} of filteredSearchItems) {
    savedFilter[saveName][id] = value;
}

console.log(savedFilter);
```

There are other, more complicated ways (`reduce`, `map` and `Object.fromEntries`, ...), but they don't have any advantage over the simple, straightfoward loop.

That said, the `map` and `Object.fromEntries` version is really concise, if that's your thing:

```
// Assumes you want to replace the [saveName] property entirely
const saveName = "fooCriteria";
savedFilter = {
    ...savedFilter,
    [saveName]: Object.fromEntries(filteredSearchItems.map(({id, value}) => [id, value]))
};
```

```js
const filteredSearchItems=[{
  "id":"das",
  "value":45
},
{
  "id":"das3",
  "value":48
},
{
  "id":"das4",
  "value":47
},
{
  "id":"das5",
  "value":46
},

];

let savedFilter = {somethingAlreadyThere: 42};
const saveName = "fooCriteria";
savedFilter = {
    ...savedFilter,
    [saveName]: Object.fromEntries(filteredSearchItems.map(({id, value}) => [id, value]))
};

console.log(savedFilter);
```

Don't be fooled, though, there's a loop in there (actually two of them, one for `map`, the other for `fromEntries`). :-)

Comment: @FaizHameed - Sorry, I missed that. I've fixed the answer to use `saveName`.

Comment: @FaizHameed - Sorry again, I hadn't fixed it everywhere. Now I have. But I think I missed a key bit of the question: That `savedFilter` may already exist and if so you want to update it. I'm fixing that now. (Yikes!)

Comment: I used your first solution my app is running fine.. thanks

Comment: @FaizHameed - Great! I've updated the answer anyway. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Using [...spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator you can do it something like this:

```js
const filteredSearchItems = [{
    "id": "das",
    "value": 45
},
{
    "id": "das3",
    "value": 48
},
{
    "id": "das4",
    "value": 47
},
{
    "id": "das5",
    "value": 46
},

]
let savedFilter = "";
const savefilter = () => {
    const saveName = "fooCriteria";
    let res = {};
    filteredSearchItems.forEach(item => {
        if (!savedFilter) {
            savedFilter = { [saveName]: { [item.id]: item.value } };
        } else
            savedFilter[saveName] = {
                ...{ [item.id]: item.value }, ...savedFilter[saveName]
            }


    });
};
savefilter();
console.log("savedFilter :", savedFilter.fooCriteria)
```

Comment: change  `savedFilter.fooCriteria` to `savedFilter[saveName]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    const filteredSearchItems=[{
      "id":"das",
      "value":45
    },
    {
      "id":"das3",
      "value":48
    },
    {
      "id":"das4",
      "value":47
    },
    {
      "id":"das5",
      "value":46    
    },

    ]
    var a1={};
    for(let i=0 ; i<filteredSearchItems.length;i++){
        let id1 = filteredSearchItems[i].id;
        let id2 = filteredSearchItems[i].value;
        a1[id1] = id2;
    }
    var t2 = {"fooCriteria": a1}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(t2));

Output : {"njkcnv":{"das":45,"das3":48,"das4":47,"das5":46}}
```